# Import and process SASS file only in dev mode with grunt

Tags: node.js, build, sass, gruntjs

I'm wanting to add a directory of files to my SASS processing in my "dev" task, or alternatively exclude it in a "build" task. Any tips for doing this well?

In a nutshell there is some css I don't want to include in the build.

Comment: [grunt.file.expand](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand) allows exclusions. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use grunt-copy task in the your dev task.

for example you have the following structure of your styles:

```
/styles
  /dev-scss
  /scss
    /main
    /dev
```

The idea is to copy the content of the "dev-scss" folder into "dev" folder only for dev grunt task.
There is only some problem, you have to clear dev folder for every other task.